# Animated border: 1px dashed #000;

Tags: jquery, css

How can I animate a element styled with:

```
border: 1px dashed #000;
```

To have this effect using jQuery or CSS3? - http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/animated-photoshop-selection-on-a-web-page#examples

Thanks ( : ) )

Comment: What's wrong with allllll the examples he gives you on that page?

Comment: It's interesting but, I don't think you can achieve that in CSS3! The example you shown is using animated GIF as a background to emulate the movement you see. Check out the source code or inspect the element in DevTools to see

Comment: I would prefer not to use an img to create the effect. jQuery and CSS3 is powerful enough to clone this effect and was interested how we can achieve this.

Comment: @Ahmad I understand how it works but there must be a better way.

Comment: You could make some kind of convoluted JavaScript solution, but it would be messy and error-prone. IMHO the background image is the cleanest solution.

Comment: The thing is, We do not have properties that allow us to control the drawing of the border itself ... Even each browser draw the dashed borders differently (http://www.impressivewebs.com/comparison-css-border-style/) We do not control any offset where should it start or what how much space between each dash. If we had control over this I would have said that we can recreate it with jQuery and CSS but no. I am hoping I am wrong and would like to see other people opinion :)

Comment: What about [border images](http://caniuse.com/#search=border%20image) ?

Comment: Here's something similar but still uses a img....http://there4development.com/projects/animatedborder/